# Cant connect to python server

Tags: python, sockets, chat

I am new in working with sockets in python, so I want create simple server: clients can connect and wait some time.

My problem is - when I connect to server from first client (**client.py**) - server logs about it, but at the same time I connect from another client to server (tablet web-browser) - and server don't logs it. He don't send messages to second client, as if it does not exist. But in code I have `listen(2)`!

Does it mean, that I must create new process for each new connection? In future I want create a very simple chat (many people, 2 in one chatroom) for training. Or can I collect connection information about clients in **clients** list, and than create process for two people?

**settings.py**

```
number_of_connections = 2
host = ''
port = 9090
```

**server.py**

```
import time
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from multiprocessing import Process
from settings import host, port, number_of_connections

def logging(message):
        print(message)
        with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('%s\n' % message)

clients = []

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind((host, port))

sock.listen(number_of_connections)

conn, addr = sock.accept() # accept connection. conn - new socket, addr - client`s adress

clients.append((conn, addr))

#conn.settimeout(60)
logging('%s Connection from %s:%s' % (time.ctime(), addr[0], addr[1]))

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    udata = data.decode("utf-8")
    logging("Server recieve Data: %s" % udata)
    #conn.send(data.upper())
    conn.send(b"Hello! From server!\n")
    conn.send(b"Your data: " + udata.encode("utf-8"))
    # if we had 2 clients, create process? 
    if len(clients) == 2:
        print(clients)
        clients.clear()
```

**client.py**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from settings import host, port

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host, port))
sock.send(b'hello, world! From client')


while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)

    print(data)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Your server only allows one connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your 'conn' variable is from the connection of the first client that the socket has connected to. Try changing your script to loop through sock.accept()

Below is your server.py with very minimum changes, so that you can see the difference.

```
import time
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from multiprocessing import Process
from settings import host, port, number_of_connections

def logging(message):
        print(message)
        with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('%s\n' % message)

clients = []

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind((host, port))

sock.listen(number_of_connections)

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    udata = data.decode("utf-8")
    logging("Server recieve Data: %s" % udata)
    conn.send(b"Hello! From server!\n")
    conn.send(b"Your data: " + udata.encode("utf-8"))
```

If you would like to know an example of chat server/client take a look at this:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/531824/

Have a read more about the concept of socket and connection, im sure it will benefit you
more in the long run as well.
Hope that helps.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this in one process.

The simplest way is to handle each connection serially. Wait for and accept an incoming connection, communicate with the peer, and then disconnect. Then wait for another connection. This doesn't handle your case where you want multiple concurrent client connections, and obviously it won't scale. Here is a revision of your code that will handle serial connections:

```
import time
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from multiprocessing import Process
from settings import host, port, number_of_connections

def logging(message):
        print(message)
        with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('%s\n' % message)

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(number_of_connections)

while True:
    logging("Waiting for connection on %s:%s" % (host, port))
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    logging('%s Connection from %s:%s' % (time.ctime(), addr[0], addr[1]))

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            # remote closed connection, close and wait for a new connection
            logging("Client closed connection")
            conn.close()
            break

        udata = data.decode("utf-8")
        logging("Server recieve Data: %s" % udata)
        #conn.send(data.upper())
        conn.send(b"Hello! From server!\n")
        conn.send(b"Your data: " + udata.encode("utf-8"))
```

However, because you actually want to handle multiple concurrent connections, it's time to investigate the [select module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#module-select) which provides functions to help with asynchronous IO (see the `select()` and/or `poll()` functions.). And the [asyncore module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html#module-asyncore) is well worth a look. [asynchat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/asynchat.html#module-asynchat) might have everything that you need.

Another option is to create a new thread or subprocess for each client.

A more sophisticated option is [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), however, there's a steep learning curve and it might be overkill for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You have listen(2), you need another handler from incoming connection.

Put

```
conn, addr = sock.accept() # accept connection
```

inside while loop.